# Cartoon styled stroke effect?

Tags: after-effects, noise

I want to get this stroke style in After Effects:

[image]

Is like it's a little little bit deformed, isn't it? Or is the filter? It seems like in some tracks is 2.5px and 2.3 in anothers... Compare with my current stroke:

[image]

Mine is more defined and 'perfect'. I need to apply these old cartoon effect in stroke.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Roughen edges" effect applied to the stroke layer - play with the settings.

Then "Add Grain" effect as an adjustment layer, as shown below:

Also see [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33422/why-effects-flow-during-camera-movement-in-after-effects-2020/33426#33426) if you need to animate the stroke with roughen edges applied to it.

[image]

Comment: Yeahhh that's the solution I wanted to. Thank you so much!!